# SpinnerList control and monitor wheel movement

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

Does anyone know how programatically:
1- Stop the SpinnerList from spinning;
2- Check in which item the spinner currently is while spinning;

The SpinnerList I am using comes from the mobile.swc components. It is a Spark component (using Flex 4.6). What I could take from the documentation is basically that I could control the SpinnerList and stop it when the user triggers a mouseDown event by manipulating the scoller used in the SpinnerList. That leads to another question how do I control the scroller. Do I need to set the scrollPolicy on/off? Isn't there a better way?

Second point I still have no idea how to do it. Even reading carefully the documentation. My dataProvider is sorted alphabetically and I would like to smoothly pop a letter showing in which letter group the Spinner entered while spinning. Sort of a first letter displayer that dynamically changes while scrolling. Something like the caret_index would be cool but it only updates once the Caret is selected.

Thanks!

Comment: Voted down. You think we can guess which SpinnerList you are talking about? Many framework use that name + many framework have different version. You really think we can read your mind?

Comment: @BotMaster I think you're too strict with him. There are tags that indicates framework.

Comment: @Crabar Good point, but that doesn't make this a good question.  Both items are easily answered by reading the documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/SpinnerList.html

Comment: I mean the SpinnerList that comes with the Flex framework 4.6 from spark. Sorry I though this was clear. @Brian Please point to me where in this documentation is the answer for my question. I am going to read the documentation again. As of other spinnerLists I would like to know where can I get my hands on another SpinnerList as I am not getting the right thing done with the Spark spinnerList.

Comment: @Dave To prevent spinning, `enabled`.  For your second question (as an aside, it's better to post two separate questions than one two-part question), I was going to point you at the `change` event, but your edit makes it sound like that won't do. TBH, I'm not sure that the kind of instant-monitoring you want to do is possible with this control.